# JavaScript Fill the table with the Set value

Tags: javascript, set

I have an array with X number of values and a table with 20 generated rows.
I need to put all the values in each row.

```
const apptid_divs11 = [...document.querySelectorAll('.apptSearchResultSelected')];
const apptid_set11 = new Set(apptid_divs11.map(div => div.textContent.trim().split('#')[0]))
//alert([...apptid_set11][2]);
var demo = document.getElementById("app_div_tbl");
demo.innerHTML =' <table style="margin: auto; width: 95%" border="1" cellspacing="0"><thead><th class="app_name" style="width: 65%"></th><th style="text-align: center;" colspan="2">Temperature</th><th style="text-align: center;">Number of pallets tipped</th></thead><tbody></tbody></table>';
let myArrayData = Array.from(Array(20), (x, i) => i);

let rows = "";

for (let rowData of myArrayData) {
    rows += `
  <tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
`;
}
document.querySelector("table tbody").innerHTML = rows;
```

The `[...apptid_set11][2]` value I need to put instead of the "asd" in the first `<td>`

I tried to put anything insted of the "asd" but nothing works with js.

UPDATE:

```
for (let rowData of myArrayData) {
            rows += `
          <tr>
            <td>${
            for ( let i = 0; i < apptid_set11.size; i++){
                  [...apptid_set11][i]
                 }
            }
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

          </tr>
        `;
enter code here
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals read this.

Comment: Why is `myArrayData` a thing when its content is never used and never changed? Just use a regular `for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) { ... }` loop. Or create `rows` directly with `Array.from({ length: 20 }, (_, i) => \`...\`).join("")`

Comment: if I put ${for (let }.... it shows error Unexpected token for. As I updated in the question

Comment: What is `[...apptid_set11][2]` supposed to mean? `[...apptid_set11]` converts the Set to an array, but the order is unpredictable, so `[2]` could be any element. Do you mean you want element `[2]` of each set element?

Comment: Just like I updated in my question. It should be [...apptid_set11][i]

Comment: The edit makes no sense... Please provide an actual [mcve] with a minimal input and the expected output for that input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code quite a bit:

```js
// const myArray=Array.from(Array(20),(_,i)=>i);
const apptid_divs11 = [...document.querySelectorAll('.apptSearchResultSelected')];
const apptid_set11 =
 [ ...new Set(apptid_divs11.map(div => div.textContent.trim().split('#')[0])),
   ...Array(20).fill("&nbsp;") ].slice(0,20);

document.getElementById("app_div_tbl").innerHTML=`
<table style="margin: auto; width: 95%" border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <th class="app_name" style="width: 65%"></th>
    <th style="text-align: center;" colspan="2">Temperature</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Number of pallets tipped</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  ${apptid_set11.map(txt=>`<tr><td>${txt}</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>`).join("")}
  </tbody>
</table>`;
```

```html
<div class="apptSearchResultSelected">one#hello</div>
<div class="apptSearchResultSelected">two#2#3</div>
<div class="apptSearchResultSelected">one#3</div>
<div class="apptSearchResultSelected">four#by#four</div>
<div class="notSelected">five#5</div>
<div class="apptSearchResultSelected">six</div>
<div class="apptSearchResultSelected">seven#up</div>
<div id="app_div_tbl"></div>
```

I changed the answer to incorporate the demand for "at least 20 rows". So the expression `...Array(20).fill("&nbsp;")` provides some further 20 elements containing `"&nbsp;"` to the initially supplied unique set of words. The total array `apptid_set11` is limited to 20 elements by applying `.slice(0,20)` to the combined array.

Comment: It's much simpler, but If I want to replace the txt to my for loop to be the txt is the same as [...apptid_set11][i], its shows "unexpected token for".

Comment: Can you show us what your set `apptid_set11` contains?

Comment: `const apptid_divs11 = [...document.querySelectorAll('.Selected')];
                    
                   const apptid_set11 = new Set(apptid_divs11.map(div => div.textContent.trim().split('#')[0]))`

Comment: I don't really understand the `const myArray=Array.from(Array(20),(_,i)=>i);` part so I don't know how to implement here my apptid_set11 .. :/

Comment: Thanks. One last thing if you could please help how can I leave to have at least 20 rows? 
(if the array.size is 10, so the rest (10) would be empty)